# Using GROUP_CONCAT and BIND to produce single statement

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to work out how SPARQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function works.

Here is the data I'm working with:
http://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203

This object has three `P43_has_dimension` properties, each with its own value and type ([1](https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203/dimension/1), [2](https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203/dimension/2), [3](https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203/dimension/3): it is 52mm in diameter, 77mm in height, and 15mm deep).

What I'd like to be returned is "52mm (diameter)"; "77mm (height)"; "15mm (depth)". In other words, each value and its corresponding type in brackets.

After looking through dozens of other questions on here, I've attempted to use [the following SPARQL query](http://yasgui.org/short/SJlwZe6U7), but to little effect:

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  ecrm: <http://erlangen-crm.org/current/>
PREFIX  tdwg: <http://rs.tdwg.org/ontology/voc/Specimen#>
PREFIX  am:   <http://collections.aucklandmuseum.com/ontology/core/>
PREFIX  foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX  dc:   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>

SELECT ?measure ?size (GROUP_CONCAT(?dimension ; separator='; ') AS ?dimensions)
WHERE
  {   { <http://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203> ecrm:P43_has_dimension/ecrm:P90_has_value ?size }
    UNION
      { <http://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203> ecrm:P43_has_dimension/ecrm:P2_has_type ?measure }
    BIND(coalesce(?size, "") AS ?size1)
    BIND(coalesce(?measure, "") AS ?measure1)
    BIND(concat(?size1, " (", ?measure1, ")") AS ?dimension)
  }
GROUP BY ?measure ?size ?dimension
```

This returns 6 results, with each `measure` and `size` in its respective column, but with none of them combined in the `dimension` column. I would appreciate any help or links to somewhere that would help with where I'm going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Note that GROUP BY and aggregates work in the exact same way in SPARQL and SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the trouble is that you're grouping on the wrong feature. You are looking to combine different dimension types and values for each individual subject. So that subject needs to be in your `GROUP_BY`. In your original query there's only one subject (`<http://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203>`), but we need to make it available as a variable to be able to group on it anyway.

Additionally, I don't think you need the union and most of the additional binds. Assuming each subject's dimensions will always have a type and a value, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(?dim) as ?dimensions)
WHERE
  {  
    VALUES ?subject { <http://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203> }
    ?subject ecrm:P43_has_dimension [ ecrm:P90_has_value ?size ;
                                      ecrm:P2_has_type ?measure ]. 
    BIND(concat(?size, " (", ?measure, ")") AS ?dim)
  } GROUP BY ?subject
```

Of course if it's not always the case that a dimension has a size  and a measure, you can use OPTIONAL and put the coalesce-construction back in again.

Comment: You could simply even more in this case: `SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(?d) as ?ds) WHERE  {  <http://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/humanhistory/object/1203>  ecrm:P43_has_dimension [ ecrm:P90_has_value ?s ; ecrm:P2_has_type ?m ]. BIND(concat(?s, " (", ?m, ")") AS ?d) }`